# Laravel Access denied

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.1, access-denied

I get following error in my laravel application. ( I am using Laravel 5.1)

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

at the details it says that I do not parse any password:

```
array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'gen', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
```

My .env file looks like this in Laravel:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=************************************

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=gen
DB_USERNAME=miad2
DB_PASSWORD=***************

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

I use phpmyadmin and created that user there.

database.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,


    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],


    'migrations' => 'migrations',


    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

I stuck here for some hours and do not know how to fix this, need some help.

Comment: Can you post your `database.php` code for the mysql.

Comment: editede(if you meant that one)

Comment: I do have to go for now do not mind if I do not answer I will later on

Comment: Did you restart your server and try?

Comment: what is DB_PASSWORD in .env? does it hold any value? you can show it. It's local anyway!

Comment: In your .env file your username is miad2, in your database.php it's either miad2 or forge (fallback)...so where does 'root' come from?

Comment: Is it using **.env.example**?

Comment: ********** holds a password yes, I also restarted my server, instead of forge in my database.php do I have to write my password?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so what I did now was changing the server name which was set to root and the password which was empty in the config.inc.php to that user i created. And Voila it worked.